# Jersey Image Upload Client

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-client, jersey-1.0

I am trying to upload image using Jersey webservice , i am using jersey client to upload image.
below is jersey web service which takes inputstream and uploads image on server. it works fine when i directly call it using jsp multipart form upload but fails when i upload images using jersey client

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) throws ServiceException
{
    // upload code
}
```

Below is Jersey Client to upload Image, the client code is part of another web service which is called from php rest client and this jersey client call to jersey web service to upload image, if i directly call jersey web service to upload image that work's fine but it is not working when i upload using jersey client.

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
client.setChunkedEncodingSize(1024);
WebResource wr = client
        .resource("http://localhost:8080/rest/upload");

String contentDisposition = "attachment; filename=\""
        + fileDetail.getName() + "\"";
FormDataMultiPart form = new FormDataMultiPart();
ContentDisposition contentDisposition2 = new ContentDisposition(contentDisposition);
form.setContentDisposition(contentDisposition2);
FormDataBodyPart fdp = new FormDataBodyPart("file",
        uploadedInputStream, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);
form.bodyPart(fdp);
ClientResponse response = wr.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).post(
        ClientResponse.class, form)
```

Please help me not sure what i am missing here.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what "not working" means? I tested with your exact code, using `FileInputStream` type for `uploadedInputStream` and it works fine. One thing I would change (though it didn't cause it to fail for me) is `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE` for `fdp` to `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE`

Comment: I mean it is passing uploadedInputStream to jersey webservice but it does not contains same chunks and same content type which we passed from jersey client.

Comment: form-data is the main content type of the request. But the form-data comes with parts and each part has it's own content type. The file should be octet-stream and not form-data

Comment: @peeskillet, you are right it should be MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a full example to upload an image using jersey client and webservice
the client code

```
public class Test {

    private static URI getBaseURI() {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/restfullwebservice/resources/generic").build("");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        final ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        final Client client = Client.create(config);

        final WebResource resource = client.resource(getBaseURI()).path("upload");

        final File fileToUpload = new File("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Desert.jpg");

        final FormDataMultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
        if (fileToUpload != null) {
            multiPart.bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("file", fileToUpload,
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE));
        }

        final ClientResponse clientResp = resource.type(
                MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class,
                multiPart);
        System.out.println("Response: " + clientResp.getClientResponseStatus());

        client.destroy();
    }
}
```

the webservice server code

```
@POST
@Path("upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public void uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) throws ServiceChannelException {
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        File fileToUpload = new File("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Desert1.jpg");
        os = new FileOutputStream(fileToUpload);
        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;
        while ((length = uploadedInputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GenericResource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GenericResource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Full application
https://github.com/abdotalaat/upladeimageusingjersy

Comment: every thing is ok with you? note that the full project is Netbeans project

Comment: Ohh i see, i never tried with netbeans but now i will try it.
Thanks for your help.